# How to read the csv files from Azure Blob Storage in Java with folder structure as 'dir1 / dir2 / dir3 / 20210301-20210331'?

Tags: java, spring-batch, azure-blob-storage

I have scheduled an export in my azure blob storage account, it's a monhtly run which creates a csv file under folder like `dir1 / dir2 / dir3 / StartDateOfMonth-EndDateOfMonth`.

I have below things to do.

1- I want to read this file in java without downloading it.

2 - Want to read parallelly using spring batch master-worker pattern.

Issue facing:-

1- I am not getting absolute path using below line

```
CloudAppendBlob cloudAppendBlob=  container.getAppendBlobReference("blob_file_name");

log.info("cloudAppendBlob.getUri().getPath() = {}",cloudAppendBlob.getUri().getPath());
```

2- If anyone helps me to how to do it in Spring Batch master-worker pattern, it would be very helpful for me. [ Normal Spring Batch master-worker pattern I know for a CSV  to read it file from local path ]

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine,

I just gave a hardcoded path of my blob file [ which is present in my Azure Blob Storage Account] to UrlResource.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine
UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("https://containerName.blob.core.windows.net/DirectoryName/dir1/dir2/DateFolder/FileName.csv");

I have got an error 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL`

Answer (score 0):

> 1- I want to read this file in java without downloading it.

You can use one of the file item readers (flat file, xml file, json file, etc) provided by Spring Batch and configure it with a `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource`. Here is a quick example:

```
UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("remote/url/to/your/file");
FlatFileItemReader<String> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
   .resource(resource)
   // set other properties
   .build();
```

> 2 - Want to read parallelly using spring batch master-worker pattern.

You can use the remote partitioning technique provided by Spring Batch where each file is processed in a partition (ie a worker per file). Spring Batch provides the [MultiResourcePartitioner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html) that was specifically designed for that. You can find more details in the [Partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) section and a complete example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample).

Comment: UrlResource resource = new UrlResource("containerName.blob.core.windows.net/DirectoryName/dir1/dir2/…); I have got an error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL

can you please suggest me how to use it ?

Comment: That's not a URL. The URL should be conform to [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for downloading the .csv files from Azure Blob Storage in Java with folder structure as 'dir1 / dir2 / dir3 / StartDateOfMonth-EndDateOfMonth'

```
@Override
        public List listBlobs(String containerName) {
                List uris = new ArrayList<>();
                String fileName=null;
                try {
                        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
                        Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = container.listBlobs("$Directory", true); //for $Directory please find screenshot I have given below. this is the name that you provide during the creation of Export in your Azure Storage account
                        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(environment.getProperty("azure.storage.ConnectionString")).buildClient();

                        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);

                        FileOutputStream fout = null;

                        for (ListBlobItem fileBlob : blobs) {
                                log.info("fileBlob instanceof CloudBlob = {}",fileBlob instanceof CloudBlob);
                                if (fileBlob instanceof CloudBlob) {
                                        CloudBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlob) fileBlob;
                                        uris.add(cloudBlob.getName());
                                        log.info("File Name is = {}", cloudBlob.getName());
                                        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(cloudBlob.getName());
                                        System.out.println(blobClient.getBlobUrl());
                                        System.out.println(blobClient.getBlobUrl().trim());
                                        if (blobClient.exists()) {
                                                Path p = Paths.get(cloudBlob.getName());
                                                String file = p.getFileName().toString();
                                                String directory = p.getParent().toString();
                                                log.info("Downloading Blob File = {} from Directory {}",file,directory);

                                                File dir = new File("$LOCAL_PATH"+directory);

                                                dir.mkdirs();
                                                fout = new FileOutputStream("$LOCAL_PATH" + cloudBlob.getName());
                                                blobClient.download(fout);


                                                CloudAppendBlob cloudAppendBlob=  container.getAppendBlobReference(cloudBlob.getName());
                                                uris.add(cloudAppendBlob.getUri().toURL());
                                                log.info("cloudAppendBlob.getUri().getPath() = {}",cloudAppendBlob.getUri().toURL());
  
                                          
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
                                uris.add(blobItem.getUri().toURL());
                                //System.out.println("blobItem.getUri().getPath()= "+blobItem.getUri().getPath());
                        }


                } catch (StorageException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return uris;
        }
```

[image]

This code will download all the files from all sub-directories, to download from the specific directory of the month, you can add a check for date matching for the directory name.